# Increment Checkbox number in ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, checkbox

I need to place the query results into the text field of three checkboxes. I need it basically to do this:

```
QuesChk0.Text = "Question 4 Here"
QuesChk1.Text = "Question 3 Here"
QuesChk2.Text = "Question 1 Here"
```

Doing QuesChk0.Text = prs[0].ToString(); will give me the first question but not the other two.
I don't know how to dynamically increment the number after the checkbox name (QuesChk0 <---).

```
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection pcn;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand pcm;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader prs;

        pcn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("");
        pcm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        pcn.Open();

        pcm.Connection = pcn;

        var tableSql = String.Format(@"SELECT TOP 3 Question FROM Questions ORDER BY NEWID()");

        pcm.CommandText = tableSql;
        prs = pcm.ExecuteReader();

        var rowcount = 0;
        while (prs.Read())
        {
            QuesChk0.Text = prs[0].ToString();
            rowcount++;
        }
        prs.Close();
        pcn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hopefully work:

First you create an array of checkboxes in the order they need to be presented:

```
CheckBox[] chks = new CheckBox[] { QuesChk0, QuesChk1, QuesChk2 };
```

Then set the text like this:

```
while (prs.Read())
{
    chks[rowcount].Text = prs[0].ToString();
    rowcount++;
}
```

Comment: I am getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array" http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9446763/Capture2.JPG

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Controls[string.Format("QuesChk{0}", rowcount)].Text = prs[rowcount].ToString();
```

Comment: I get an argument with that "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'"

Comment: I cannot find a mistake in my solution works here as intended. :(

Comment: "prs[0]" should be "prs[rowcount]".

Comment: Yes, you are right. I copied that part from the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the solution @Alina gave, You can try

```
(this.FindControl(string.Format("QuesChk{0}", rowcount)) as CheckBox).Text = prs[rowcount].ToString();
```

Comment: With that I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."